# How to pass data to multiple blades in laravel and with a single route

Tags: php, laravel-5

i have tried to passing data to multiple blade in controller but get error. Here bellow my code

```
public function index()
{
    $news = DB::table('beritas')
            ->select('id','judul_berita','created_at')
            ->get();

    return view (['berita.daftar-berita', 'more-menu.berita'])->with(compact('news'));
}
```

How to pass data to multiple blades in laravel and with a single route?

Comment: I have a doubt. Why to pass data to multiple blades? I think you can return only one blade.

Comment: Return a blade and include the other blade in the generated blade and use the data for both.

Comment: @WhatIf this will not be feasible if you only want the data from the blade file. If you just ```@include``` the other file you will also get all the styling and markup that comes with it. I think OP wants to know how to share ONLY the data.

Answer (score 1):

If u want pass data to multiple blades u can share it in the Constructor like so:

```
public function __construct(){

      $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {

           $news = DB::table('beritas')>select('id','judul_berita','created_at')->get();
           View::share('news', $news);
           return $next($request);
        });

    }
```

and now u can use news variable in all you blades that using the same controller.

i hope it's will help you

Comment: Please accept this at the best answer by clicking True symbol

Comment: View Share concept. Nice. Thanks @Abdessamad

Answer (score 0):

Probably the right place to this is in the boot method of some service provider, for example, AppServiceProvide.

```
//AppServiceProvider.php 

public function boot()
{
   view()->share('someVariable',$someVariable);

}
```

This will make someVariable available to all of blade views. This is useful for template level variables.